# Best way to "monitor" the Solana blockchain?

Tags: python, jsonrpc-api

this isn't normally the kind of question I would ask on stack overflow, but please bear with me! Given this is the replacement for the dev-support discord channel I'm hoping that some people may be able to provide some advice for our current project.

The app that we are currently developing takes advantage of Solanas rapid block production rate by using it to set it's 'heartbeat'. Every time a new block is produced the state of an off-chain component of the app updates, and users can decide how the state will update by interacting with an on-chain program. Even if no-one uses the program within a given block however, the state of the off-chain program will still update (imagine any video game where even if you aren't pressing buttons, time is still passing in the game world).

We have a Quicknode RPC entrypoint that we are using to run a 'monitoring server' that essentially just does the following in a loop:

i) use getblocks to request the set of finalized blocks since the last iteration
ii) submit batch requests for getblock to get those blocks
iii) process those blocks and add the info our app uses to a database

One key requirement of our monitoring system is that when running live, and producing the database in realtime, it should yield exactly the same result as someone who simply downloads the data from the blockchain months or years later and builds their own database when all the blocks are available historically. Both the on and off-chain apps will be available for anyone to run themselves, and are being designed so that anyone using the same starting block should be able to retrieve the history of the chain from that point, and arrive at the same current state in order to verify that everything is working as advertised. We therefore have to ensure that the events in the live database will never be out of order due to the asynchronous nature of requesting information from the API.

We've written a blog post on what we are doing here: https://www.daoplays.org/blog/solana_streamer, with example code on our github repo (https://github.com/daoplays/solana_examples/tree/master/solana_streamer/) which has the python code, and also the toy rust program/client that it is referencing.

Currently this uses about 300k API requests a day (so 9 million a month!), but i'm really not  sure how else we could do this given the constraints we have, which is where I was hoping someone  might be able to offer any alternate suggestions.

Hopefully this sort of question is allowed :s  Apologies if not, and thank you to anyone that takes the time to comment.

Comment: this is going to elicit opinionated responses, is unclear and does not ask a concise question. so i'm voting to close

Comment: Given the dev support discord is now closed, where should we ask for opinions?

Comment: it's not a good question for discord either.  it should be reworded such that it asks a single, clear, concise question that will elicit objective answers

Answer (score 1):

You should really be looking into running a geyser plugin. It’ll give you push instead of pull, meaning you don’t need the 300k api calls.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins

Comment: don't you need to be running a self hosted validator to be able to deploy custom Geyser plugins? that probably prices most people out of this option

Comment: Yes that’s correct. A geyser plugin is the “best way” but you need a validator. Roughly 10million api calls a month  isn’t free either.

Comment: Now that Solana ecosystem has matured and gave us the necessary tooling... the correct answer is to rely on services such as Helius and their webhooks for pushing on-chain events whenever you need them pushed at. 

https://docs.helius.xyz/webhooks/what-are-webhooks

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use blockSubscribe instead of getBlocks()?

This would also give you a push instead of a pull, and with block subscribe you can add a "mention" filter that will eliminate unrelated transactions, allowing you to "sub sample" the ledger, giving you a view of the ledger that has only data relevant to your app or program.

One strategy I'm trying right now is to then also run "getSignaturesForAddress()" on some interval, using the same "mentions" filter. If that request returns a block that I don't have, then I missed it, and I can go get it.

If you need to replicate the entire ledger though, then you probably do need to use geyser.